# Change file name when using write.table() according to the name of the third column in data frame

Tags: r

I wrote a script in R that merges and modifies some csv data and then saves the resulting data frame using write table(). When it saves the file it adds the current date to the name of the file. The third column of the resulting data frame is always country specific, so I was wondering if there is a way to include in the file name using write.table the name of the country depending on the country code (name of the third column).

For example, if the name of the third column is "it", I want to add "Italy" to the name of the csv file using write.table.

Comment: does the answer proposed below address your need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import list of country names and codes into R: (*It would be wise to do this at the very top of your script: outside your processing loop so you dont read in the data over and over for each dataset being written out to .csv. The rest of the code goes just before your current `write.table` command*

```
library(RCurl)
csv_src <- getURL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/umpirsky/country-list/master/country/cldr/en/country.csv")

world <- read.csv(text=csv_src, header=T)`
```

Get name of third column in your data with country codes:

`countrycode <- colnames(yourdata)[3]`

Extract corresponding country name:

```
country_idx <- grep(pattern=countrycode, x=world$iso, ignore.case = TRUE)

country <- world$name[country_idx]
```

Attach country name to csv filename (*Replace "..." with whatever other tags you want appended to the output filename. Otherwise remove "..."*)

```
csv_name <- paste0("...",country, ".csv")
```

Write out your data to file:

```
write.table(x=yourdata, file=csv_name)
```

Good luck :-)

Comment: Thanks, this was useful. In my particular case I could use a shortcut after the countrycode <- colnames(yourdata)[3] by including an ifelse inside the paste function (since the country codes were included in the names of the third column, it includes the name of the country in the file if it matches a certain country code)

Comment: Super, glad to help, need to get my way round `ifelse`, seems handy.